# dygraph x-y plot with floating points for x-axis values

Tags: dygraphs

I am trying to plot some multi-column x-y data. If the x-axis is an integer, then all is fine. But if the x-axis is a float (which is what I want), I get:

```
"Couldn't parse 2.214844 as a date"
...
```

as errors in the console. How do I plot floating points for x-axis?

Example of data:

```
2.214844,,,,,0.000000
2.224854,,,,0.000000,
2.234131,0.000000,,,,
2.264893,,,0.000000,,
2.273193,,0.000000,,,
104.372070,,,,0.000000,
104.376709,,,,,0.000000
104.398193,0.000000,,,,
104.498047,,,0.000000,,
104.577148,,0.000000,,,
```

My code so far:

```
g = new Dygraph(
            document.getElementById("graphdiv"),
            "./a.csv", 
          {
             labels: ['time','1','2','3','4','5'],
             visibility: [true, false, false,false,false],
             axes: { x: {
                          //valueParser: function(x) {return parseFloat(x);},
                          valueParser: function(x) {return parseInt(x);}
                        }
                   }
           });
```

I tried with and without the axis options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've found quite the bug! dygraphs decides whether your x-values are dates or numbers based on the first one ("2.214844"). In this case, [because of an imprecise check](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/issues/939), it gets it wrong.

This will get fixed in the next dygraphs release. But in the meantime, your options are either to:

1. Add or remove a single digit from that value, i.e. make it "2.2148440" with a zero on the end. (Seriously!)
2. Explicitly tell dygraphs that your x-axis is numeric.

This is what that would look like:

```
g = new Dygraph(
    document.getElementById("graph"),
    csv,
    {
       xValueParser: parseFloat,
       axes: {
         x: {
           valueFormatter: x => x,
           ticker: Dygraph.numericTicks,
           axisLabelFormatter: x => x,
         }
       }
    }
);
```

See [full example](https://jsfiddle.net/0h1z72s0/3340/).